# Template definition outside class in DLL (error: definition of dllimport function not allowed)

Tags: c++, templates, dll

I'm getting following compiler error:
[Compiler Error C2491 'identifier' : definition of dllimport function not allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2491)

The bellow code does not work just because template definition is outside class, if I put the definition inside class compilation is OK.

What I want to achieve is to have definition outside the class, is that possible?

Here is a header and source file inside DLL project (defines COMPILE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)):

**DLLHeader.h**

```
#pragma once

// DLL export/import symbols
#ifdef COMPILE_DLL
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined (LINK_DLL)
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

template<typename T>
class DLL_API FromDLL
{
public:
    ~FromDLL();
};

// error C2491: 'FromDLL<T>::~FromDLL': definition of dllimport function not allowed
// no error if definition put inside class
template<typename T>
FromDLL<T>::~FromDLL()
{
}
```

**DLLSource.cpp**

```
#include "DLLHeader.h"

// Explicit intantation for DLL export
template class DLL_API FromDLL<int>;
```

And here is client code which used the DLL (defines LINK_DLL __declspec(dllimport))

**Client.cpp**

```
#define LINK_DLL
#include "DLLHeader.h"


int main()
{
    FromDLL<int> instance;

    // EDI: I also want to reuse template code
    FromDLL<float> instance;
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to export the implementation from the DLL, it doesn't make sense to put it into the header. If you do, the caller will just inline it, and won't actually link to the DLL implementation. Move it to the source file.

Comment: Is that simple? thank you, I thought definition always must be in a header, but this case is different obviously. The problem is other interfaces inside DLL need this class to have DLL interface(because they have members of this template) that's why I need to export all instantations. please make an answer if you want so I can accept.

Comment: Ah wait, but then the problem is client code can't reuse this template with their own types, if definition is not visible.  without exporting first. It look like I have no other choice but to put definition into the class.

Comment: Do you want it to? Then what's the purpose of the DLL? Anyway, if that's what you want, don't mark `FromDLL` class with `DLL_API`, but only the explicit instantiation. Mention it in the header, like this: `extern template class DLL_API FromDLL<int>;` This way, the client that uses that instance will take it from the DLL; any other instance would be inlined into the client normally.

Comment: Very interesting! but, just `extern template class FromDLL<int>;` seems to be needed, because: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4910?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C4910)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=vs-2019 And client code seems to pick up extern instantation from the DLL